# .NET - Why does one need to add assembly references to web.config?

Tags: .net

For several assemblies, it is not enough to add them as references in visual Studio, but they also need to be present under the compilation / assemblies section in the web.config.

Why? It does make things so much more troublesome in large Projects:

- When changing references by removing/adding them, it does not update
  the web.config
- Nuget does add the references but does not add an entry in web.config

Also, one needs to specify the public key token. What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

I believe aspx pages are dynamically compiled and if you do not provide full type information when specifying types in a aspx page then how would the aspx page be compiled? (i.e. How would it know which assembly to find a type in?)

By specifying assemblies in the web.config I believe you can then specify types in aspx pages without using the fully qualified type name as the page compiler will automatically load these assemblies for resolving types.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's only needed when deploying uncompiled `.cs` files for dynamic compilation. If you are deploying compiled assemblies, that section in `web.config` should not be needed at all.